# tomcat cluster apache in front - How to load balance?

Tags: apache, tomcat

What apache module would fit better to build the following cluster:
2x Red Hat each has a tomcat an apache.
No Scalability needs.
High availability needs.
Session replication needs.

```
          DNS
           |
     Load Balancer
      /           \
  APACHE1      APACHE2
  TOMCAT1      TOMCAT2
```

The question is regarding what module to use for the load balancing with apache?

mod_proxy
mod_cluster
other?

Comment: What does this have to do with Puppet?

Comment: sorry - nothing - you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand `mod_cluster` correctly, it must be used with JBoss, or with a modified Tomcat. So if you are using plain-old Tomcat (or TomEE), then I think `mod_cluster` is out.

The easiest out-of-the box option is to use `mod_proxy` with either the AJP or HTTP back-end. If you are comfortable building additional modules, `mod_jk` is available from the Tomcat folks and offers a few advantages over `mod_proxy`, though `mod_proxy` has nearly achieved feature-parity.

Your diagram suggests that a load-balancer will be choosing between two httpd instances which are coupled directly to a single Tomcat instance each. In that scenario, httpd is not performing any load-balancing at all (the lb is doing the work), and so httpd might be superfluous in that configuration.

If you instead want to cross-link both httpds with both Tomcats, that's when you start having to configure cluster-like behavior with `mod_proxy`'s "balancer" configurations. It would look something like this:

```
<Proxy balancer://appA>
  BalancerMember http://tomcatA:8080/appA
  BalancerMember http://tomcatB:8380/appA
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /appA balancer://appA
ProxyPassReverse /appA balancer://appA
```

There are [tons of options for `mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) that you should read about and apply to suit your configuration. You can configure things like sticky-sessions, hot-standbys (not present in your example diagram but a good idea if you really need HA), and asymmetric load-balancing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Apache in front is not yet decided, and there will be a couple of tomcat instances per server, I would like them to run in both nodes for high availability, the point here is how to configure tomcat, what will be in front will be decided later on. Thanks again

Comment: Aah, okay. There are some slight advantages to using `AJP` IMO, but you will be happy with either `mod_proxy` (`_ajp` or `_http`) or `mod_jk`. `mod_proxy` has the advantage of shipping directly with httpd instead of being an add-on module. The Tomcat configuration is largely proxy-agnostic (other than the choice of `HTTP` vs `AJP` protocol, of course). (Your original question specifically asks which httpd module to use, not how to configure Tomcat.)

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, mod_cluster works with any Tomcat 6+. One just needs [to put mod_cluster jars in  the lib directory](http://modcluster.io/documentation/#installing-in-tomcat-1) and [add mod_cluster Listener in server.xml](http://modcluster.io/documentation/#lifecycle-listener). The biggest advantage is that Tomcats report to httpd automatically, no need to configure any worker hostnames, ports or application contexts on the httpd side. It is completely dynamic.

Comment: @MichalKarmBabacek Thanks for the info; I'm obviously unfamiliar with `mod_cluster`. My personal preference would be to explicitly-configure the reverse-proxy rather than allowing the back-end node to configure it automatically. I would recommend this for several reasons including as a layer of security: a compromised node shouldn't be able to advertise new services through the reverse-proxy.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, well, it depends on the setup. When there are numerous worker nodes being dynamically started and stopped over the day or week, e.g. due to expected periodic peaks in traffic, the dynamic nature of self-configured load balancing mod_cluster proxy becomes a very convenient way to handle it. Furthermore, mod_cluster uses mod_proxy logic internally and it is compatible with ProxyPass settings, so you could use both within the same httpd instance. You could have some workers configured static and some handled dynamically by mod_cluster. Thanks for your comments Chris.

Comment: @MichalKarmBabacek Aah, I hadn't thought of it that way. I was more thinking that the nodes would be advertising *new* services rather than simply joining an existing cluster of previously-advertised services. I can definitely see the advantage in that.